# keyof object property values in array

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to get an array-like list of possible values consisting of object property values in array?

I have an object like this:

```
const columns: SomeType[] = [
  {
    name: "first",
    someProp: true
  },
  {
    name: "second",
    someProp: true
  },
  {
    name: "one more",
    someProp: true
  },
];
```

and I want to have a function that accepts a string which is values of `name` property of objects in array:

```
function someFunc(column: TypeThatILookingFor) {
  // do stuff
}
```

So I want to have something like a result of `columns.map(item => item.name)` as a type and function should accept only one value that is one of `['first', 'second', 'one more']`.

Comment: What's `SomeType`? Why not have an actual object structure as opposed to an array?

Comment: @jcalz yeah! this playground example is absolutely what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to extract from `columns` both the order and the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `name` properties of each element. But if you try to [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the type of `columns` as an unordered array type like `SomeType[]` then, no matter what `SomeType` is, you'll be losing track of the specific order.  You *could* change the annotated type to a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), but once you do that you'll find that you also need to specify the string literal types of the `name` properties in each tuple element, and pretty soon you're writing out a complex type in addition to the initializing value, which is redundant and annoying.

Instead of annotating the type, you really want to *infer* the type from the initializing value, asking the compiler to keep track of the order and the literal types.  And for that you should use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to express the intent that you're not going to modify the value and that you'd like to know as much about its shape as possible:

```
const columns = [
  { name: "first", someProp: true },
  { name: "second", someProp: true },
  { name: "one more", someProp: true }
] as const;

/* const columns: readonly [{
    readonly name: "first";
    readonly someProp: true;
}, {
    readonly name: "second";
    readonly someProp: true;
}, {
    readonly name: "one more";
    readonly someProp: true;
}] */
```

You can see from IntelliSense that the type of `columns` has all the information you care about, and we can proceed.

---

We can write a utility type called `NameMap<T>` in which `T` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be an arraylike type of elements with a `string`-valued `name` property, and which returns a corresponding arraylike type of just those `name` property types:

```
type NameMap<T extends readonly { name: string }[]> =
  { [I in keyof T]: T[I]['name'] }
```

That's a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), and [mapped types over generic array/tuple types produce array/tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).  For each numericlike index `I` in the keys of `T`, we take the element type `T[I]` ([indexing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into `T` with the index `I`) and index into it further to get the type of the `name` property: `T[I]['name']`.

Let's test it out:

```
type TypeThatILookingFor = NameMap<typeof columns>;
// type TypeThatILookingFor = readonly ["first", "second", "one more"]
```

Looks good.  The input type is `typeof columns` using [the `typeof` type query operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) to extract the type of the `columns` value, and the output type is `readonly ["first", "second", "one more"]`, exactly what you're looking for.

(Technically you were asking for `["first", "second", "one more"]` and this is a [`readonly` tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) instead, but `readonly` array types are more permissive than read-write array types, so this shouldn't stop you.  If you really care you can use the `-readonly` [mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) inside `NameMap` to change it.)

Just to be sure:

```
function someFunc(column: TypeThatILookingFor) {
  // do stuff
}

someFunc(["first", "second", "one more"]); // okay;
someFunc(["first", "next", "one more"]); // error!
// --------------> ~~~~~~
// Type '"next"' is not assignable to type '"second"'.
someFunc(["first", "second"]); // error!
// ----> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//   Source has 2 element(s) but target requires 3.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-KfTgeK8SEmh1t40QkInxgECwbwQBjA0gAI3g4igIHlVIXXRNK4AdDgKym0wUa1mr23CxGuz3+xHxzBp-+AMAidZ3wABlEBECYYBxAZHwACZniPCgwCgd0IFDfdEFgKASCYYFyFgGwAEdEGYcgfAAZlvIA)